# akka: combination of Actor and Agent

Tags: asynchronous, akka, reactive-programming, actor, agent

1. Mostly used [akka](http://akka.io/) primitive is [Actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.16/scala/actors.html#defining-an-actor-class) - any state changes or state queries are done exclusively via async messages.
2. Akka also provides less-known primitive [Agent](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/agents.html#Reading_an_Agent's_value), which is updated asynchronously by new value (or by function modifying his value) ans can be read synchronously from any thread.

**Question:** In single-JVM Actor system, how to combine these approaches: have primitive which is updated by async. messages only (like `Actor`) but which state can be read directly in thread-safe manner (like `Agent`) **?**

I would really appreciate link to any relevant discussion/project/sample.

**Solutions I found so far:**

1. Obvious possibility is to have `Actor` which updates `Agent` in `receive()`. But I am wondering if there is more elegant & performant solution.
2. [Scalaz Agent](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2014/agents.html), but solution without scalaz dependency would be prefered.
3. Half-way dirty solution: break `Actor` separation by publishing (in outgoing message) function for reading actor's state, similar to `Agent.get()`. Thread-safety must be taken care of manually.
4. Work around: let `Actor` update some external shared state in `receive()`. Thread-safety must be taken care of manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that agents have been flagged as **deprecated** by the Akka Team, and will be removed at the next major release (probably 2.5.0). [This](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/21423) is the corresponding ticket.

Indeed, the core idea of Akka is to encourage asynchronous communication, so I guess ditching Agents makes sense from this perspective.

An alternative solution might be to use an Actor and asynchronously access its state. If this scenario concerns you as a `Get` message might need to wait until a few `Update` messages are processed, you can consider using a Priority Mailbox to process `Get` messages first. Example [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/mailboxes.html#PriorityMailbox).